# How solve consumer/producer task using semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a SimpleProducerConsumer class that illustrates a consumer/producer problem (I am not sure that it's correct).

```
public class SimpleProducerConsumer {
    private Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<Object>();
    private static final int STACK_MAX_SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleProducerConsumer pc = new SimpleProducerConsumer();
        new Thread(pc.new Producer(), "p1").start();
        new Thread(pc.new Producer(), "p2").start();
        new Thread(pc.new Consumer(), "c1").start();
        new Thread(pc.new Consumer(), "c2").start();
        new Thread(pc.new Consumer(), "c3").start();
    }

    public synchronized void push(Object d) {
        while (stack.size() >= STACK_MAX_SIZE)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stack.push(new Object());
        System.out.println("push " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "    " + stack.size());
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized Object pop() {
        while (stack.size() == 0)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stack.pop();
        System.out.println("pop  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "    " + stack.size());
        notify();
        return null;
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                pop();
            }
        }
    }

    class Producer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                push(new Object());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found simple realization of semaphore [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). (I know that there is concurrency package)
How do I need to change code to exchange the java object's monitors to my custom semaphore? (To illustrate C/P problem using semaphores)

Semaphore:

```
class Semaphore {
    private int counter;

    public Semaphore() {
        this(0);
    }

    public Semaphore(int i) {
        if (i < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(i + " < 0");
        counter = i;
    }

    public synchronized void release() {
        if (counter == 0) {
            notify();
        }
        counter++;
    }

    public synchronized void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
        while (counter == 0) {
            wait();
        }
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd start over using a single shared `BlockingQueue` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but I want to understand how to solve this task using semaphores.

Comment: @stevevls - I suspect coursework here.  I replied to a very similar post yesterday...

Comment: It's only for myself(self-education).

Comment: Use [the source](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/), Luke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should fix your test app. What's with the sleep() calls?  I could understand them, maybe, in the 'Producer', 'Consumer' test threads, but why are they in the push/pop methods?  Also, the test threads transfer some object, but there is no check that each pushed object is popped exactly once.

A semaphore-based producer-consumer queue is fairly trivial. A bounded queue based solely on semaphores needs three, one initialized to zero to count objects in the queue, another initialized to the queue size to count empty slots and one initialized to 1 to act as a mutex and protect the queue from multiple access.  Just Google 'producer consumer'.

Testing can be done with two queues and a message class that has an int count. Create a lot of objects with a sequential count and push them onto one queue, then start a load of threads that shuffle objects around the two queues.  When you stop the threads, (OK, you need a terminate bool as well), the two queues should contain all the original objects - no extras, no shortages and no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea to decouple consumers from producers is to stick a queue in the middle with well defined concurrency properties.

Java provides the [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface for this purpose.

The only things that your producers and consumers have to do is `take()` and `put()` on the queue. This also gives you the advantage of scalability, as you can add multiple producers/consumers as you need.

Comment: Why don't you [checkout the Java source](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/) to see how it's really done?