# How to write Producer-Consumer solution using Message passing?

Tags: java

I found the next code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        producer.start();
        new Consumer(producer).start();
    }
}
class Producer extends Thread {
    static final int MAXQUEUE = 5;
    private Vector<String> messages = new Vector<String>();

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                putMessage();
                sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private synchronized void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {

        while (messages.size() == MAXQUEUE)
            wait();
        messages.addElement(new java.util.Date().toString());
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized String getMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        notify();
        while (messages.size() == 0)
            wait();
        String message = (String) messages.firstElement();
        messages.removeElement(message);
        return message;
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread {
    Producer producer;

    Consumer(Producer p) {
        producer = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String message = producer.getMessage();
                System.out.println("Got message: " + message);
                sleep(2000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

So as I understand Message passing  - is only not use shared resources and use like in above sample reference from one object to another to communicate. Am i right?

Comment: Related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906356/how-solve-consumer-producer-task-using-semaphores

Comment: Is this homework?  You've been asking a wide range of questions on this topic for at least a day now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the [Publish/Subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) then you need a message [queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) of some sort. The Producer puts messages on the queue and Consumer reads messages of the queue.

The point of messaging is that your producers/consumers don't have to reference each other directly but only communicate via a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Why write it yourself? You can use existing Java Message Service (JMS) solutions like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/). It can run in-process and pass messages between your objects.

Comment: I want to understand the main idea.This is a test sample.